# Solve Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relation

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence relation. I've gotten through two iterations, but I don't see any pattern. I would appreciate any help with this.

$T(1)=1$

$T(n)=6\ T(n/6)\ +\ 2n\ +\ 3$

I've manually ran through two iterations and found the following:

$T(n/6)= 36T(n/36)+14n+21$

$T(n/36)=216(n/216)+86n+129$

The pattern that I see is:

$T(n) = 6^k(n/(6^k))+ (I\ can't\ determine\ the\ pattern\ of\ these\ terms)$

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$T(n)=6\ T(n/6)\ +\ 2n\ +\ 3$$

$$T(n)=6\ (6\ T(n/6^2)\ +\ 2(n/6)\ +\ 3)\ +\ 2n\ +\ 3$$

$$T(n)=6\ (6\ (6\ T(n/6^3)\ +\ 2(n/6^2)\ +\ 3)\ +\ 2(n/6)\ +\ 3)\ +\ 2n\ +\ 3$$

Distribute the 6's.

Comment: as a general rule you'll want to expand your stuff out like this so you can see the pattern more easily, rather than grouping over and again

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier solving this using the **[Master Theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T68vN1FNY4o&t=5s)**.

T(n) = 6T(n/6) + 2n + 3

[image]


So in this case **A=6**, **B=6**, and **D=1** because **f(n) = 2n + 3** and 2n^1 + 3 = 2n + 3

We of course assume the base case is a constant such that **T(1) = C**

So we can easily see that the answer for this is 

  **T
  (
  n
  )
  =
  Θ
  (
  n log n
  )**
, since A is equal to B to the power of D.

We can see that is true just by plugging in the values

= A = B^D

= 6 = 6^1

= 2 > 1 (which is always true)

This guy on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSX8jFgTCz0&t=15s) has a very nice video explaining how to solve recurrences using the Master theorem, I will leave the link [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSX8jFgTCz0&t=15s)